# What are the benefits of quantum teleportation of continuous variables over discrete variables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

I have been learning about quantum teleportation in general and I was wondering what was the motivation behind achieving quantum teleportation of continuous 
variables.

Edit: I'm aware that it is used in order to teleport cv systems, I'm asking if it has additional benefits apart from that, for example generalising the protocol to other types of systems.

Comment: Well, if you have a system described by continuous variables and you want to teleport it ... what else should you do?

Comment: I've read something about being able to use the procedures used in cv teleportation for other types of systems, but I don't really remember where I read that and if that is even possible, so I'm basically wondering if there are more benefits apart from teleporting cv systems.

Comment: Then you should ask that!